# ffmpeg and 7160 HD Capture card error, already set rtbufsize 2000M, still real time buffer too full

Tags: ffmpeg

The 7160 Capture card original video was shown fine in the Honestech HD DVR software that is included.

However, when the card was captured using ffmpeg and publish out. This error occurred after a while running ffmpeg:

real-time buffer [7160 HD Capture] video input too full or near too full ...

I have already set -rtbufsize 2000M which is nearly the maximum that is allowed and can not be increased further.

Please tell me how to resolve this bug or give me an example that can be used without producing this bug. Thank you very much. You do not neeed the code that I used because almost any code even the simplest code I used produced this error after running for a while. The published video also lag and lost.

Comment: I found the solution. WOW

Comment: solution (and full console output) please?

Comment: ffmpeg -threads 6 -rtbufsize 2000M -f dshow -video_size 1920x1080 -i video="7160 HD Capture":audio="7160 HD Capture" -acodec aac -ar 48000 -strict experimental -vcodec libx264 -x264opts keyint=25:min-keyint=20 -b:v 2048k -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency  -r 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/fcap1

Comment: This solution shows a little bit in the delay for Wowza 4 (still died after sometimes with writeN RTMP send error on ffmpeg), for Wowza 2, it runs nicely for about 10 min and stops but the ffmpeg process still keeps running (but in reality the streaming process does not work) , I see the log of Wowza 2 and it shows Zero sized function in wowza log, for ffmpeg it shows yellow warning QUEUE INPUT IS BACKWARD IN TIME (ffmpeg still was running but no streaming process is available on wowza).

Comment: Searching on Internet they say 'zero sized function' error is something with long pause, I tried to modified setenv.sh in several ways according to the performance tuning wowza page, but that still does not solve the problem.  Do you know how to solve this QUEUE INPUT IS BACKWARD IN TIME and ZERO SIZED FUNCTION?

Comment: hmm my guess is the connection fails somehow but ffmpeg doesn't detect it [ffmpeg bug?]

Comment: I figured out a good solution for this. This is because the network bandwidth where ffmpeg is run is limited. This leads to rtbufsize error and Wowza by default do not handle rtbufsize 2000M case --> leads to Zero typed function.
Solution is to Reduce -rtbufsize to 700M and use a good network (although it is possible, avoid playing video on the same machine to save bandwidth and avoid delays).

This following command solves the problem for the 7160 HD Capture card:

Comment: ffmpeg -threads 6 -rtbufsize 700M -thread_queue_size 100 -f dshow -video_size 1280x720 -i video="7160 HD Capture":audio="7160 HD Capture" -i logo1.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=137:577" -vcodec libx264 -b:v 2048k -preset superfast -tune zerolatency -r 24 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -strict experimental -f flv - | ffmpeg -i - -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f flv rtmp://server:1935/live/test